# Display color legend on tableau chart

Tags: tableau-api

**Is there a way to display color legend on the top left side of a chart .**

I have  4 charts in a tableau dashboard and if i display all the legends for all the 4 charts on the bottom it looks busy so I want to include the legends in the charts.

Please help me on this with  details steps.

Answer (score 4):

What you want is to make the "legend" a floating object instead of the default tiled object.

To achieve this; You can hold down the Shift key, then drag the legend using the left mouse button while still holding down the Shift key. Drop the legend wherever you wish on the dashboard. Make sure you only release the Shift key after you have dropped the legend at your desired destination.

Warning: Depending on the size of the dashboard you selected, floating objects move around when end users view your dashboard on a device with different screen resolution. To avoid this you can use the "Exactly" size option and define a size range which suits your needs.

Comment: Yes, I have the issue when end users view my dashboard. Floating object are moving around the dashboard. Can you please suggest me a solution to set the color legend on the chart fixed. When I try to select the floating object and try to uncheck the floating option i was unable to do... any solution plz.

Comment: If you're using floating you should also be using fixed sized dashboards, floating doesn't work well with automatic resizing dashboards at all.   To fix this problem, tile the legend (as before) but below each individual graph.  You can put the legend above the graph, but personally I don't like that layout.

Answer (score 1):

**To include legends on top left Side of the chart.**

Follow steps here as under:

Step1:

Select legends, Right Click on legends top part and select floating and place inside the chart on the top part below heading of Graph as :[image]

So you can follow above steps to add legends in all 4 charts.

Output will look like as [image]

So in this way your legends will not be clumsy and you can describe visualization in a better manner.